# Adding an appendix to table of content for thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am using LaTeX for my thesis and I am trying to get the formatting to meet the graduate school standards. Everything is good except my table of content.[image: Table of Content]

The last line 'Chapter A...' I need to be 'Appendix A...'.
My appendix page is correct though. 
[image]

In the thesis class file I add the following lines (My thesis class is in the report class).

```
    \newcommand*{\th@DefTheChapterName}{\th@ChapHead{CHAPTER}}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{\th@DefTheChapterName}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchappresnum}{\th@DefTheChapterName\space}

    \renewcommand{\appendix}{
    \renewcommand*{\th@DefTheChapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
    \renewcommand*{\th@DefTheChapterName}{\th@ChapHead{APPENDIX}}
    }
```

EDIT
Here is an example file.

```
   \documentclass[defaultstyle,11pt]{report}
   \RequirePackage{tocloft} 
   \newcommand{\DefTheChapterName}{CHAPTER}
   \cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{8em} % moves over chapter title
   \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\DefTheChapterName\space}
   \newcommand*{\DefTheChapter}{\arabic{chapter}}

   \renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\DefTheChapter}
   \renewcommand{\appendix}
   {
       \setcounter{chapter}{0}
       \renewcommand{\DefTheChapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
       \renewcommand{\DefTheChapterName}{APPENDIX}
   }
   \begin{document}
   \tableofcontents*
   \chapter{First Chapter}
   Test Chapter

   %%%%%%%%%   then the Bibliography, if any   %%%%%%%%%
   \bibliographystyle{plain}    % or "siam", or "alpha", etc.
   \nocite{*}       % list all refs in database, cited or not
   \bibliography{refs}      % Bib database in "refs.bib"

   %%%%%%%%%   then the Appendices, if any   %%%%%%%%%
   \appendix
   \chapter{First Appendix}
   Test Appendix


   \end{document}
```

I have seen examples using the appendix package, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it without that package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Such fragments of code are not useful since there are 10000000000000000000000000  versions of `thesis` class files (and not every one is to recommend at all)

Comment: Maybe the https://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix package can help. But without a compilable example hard to guess.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to load `tocloft`, try adding this to your preamble (found on this site once, but I can't remember where):

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```